# Using SimpleTest on multivalue checkboxes

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, multi-select, simpletest

I have a form with several sets of multi-value checkboxes and a text field.  These inputs are used to build a query.

```
<input class="entry" name="search_text" />

<input type="checkbox" name="arrSource[pn_oem]" value="pn_oem" />
<input type="checkbox" name="arrSource[descr]" value="descr" />
<input type="checkbox" name="arrSource[supplier_pn]" value="supplier_pn" />
        <!---  etc  -->

<input type="checkbox" name="arrSupplier[]" value="307" /> Adam
<input type="checkbox" name="arrSupplier[]" value="113" /> Alan
<input type="checkbox" name="arrSupplier[]" value="2" /> Alex
<input type="checkbox" name="arrSupplier[]" value="3" /> Archie
        <!---  etc  -->

<input class="submit" value="Search" type="submit" name="Search" />
<input class="submit" value="Reset" type="submit" name="Reset" />
```

I've been testing the form by running a search and comparing the results with my own SQL on the database.  It seems to work perfectly.  But I haven't been able to get SimpleTest to agree (following these somewhat [sparse instructions](http://www.simpletest.org/en/form_testing_documentation.html)).  The form submittal looks like this:

```
$this->setField('arrSource[]', array("supplier_pn", "pn_oem")); 
$this->setField('arrSupplier[]', array(15,92));
$this->setField('search_text', "pax");
$this->click('Search');
```

SimpleTest produces a result of 2 but other methods say 9.  Here are some variations:

**2 but should be 9:** `setField('arrSource[]', array("supplier_pn", "pn_oem"));`

**2 but should be 0:** `setField('arrSource[]', array("pn_oem"));`

**23 but should be 2:** `setField('arrSource[]', array("supplier_pn"));`

I was able to make the UI show 2 results by setting no Supplier criteria and Source criteria as 'pn_oem' only.  This is equivalent to un-checking all the checkboxes, because the query assumes `pn_oem` is wanted if nothing is checked for Source.  Here's how that looks in SimpleTest -- and SimpleTest agreed on a result of 2:

```
$this->setField('arrSource[]', array("pn_oem")); 
$this->setField('search_text', "pax");
$this->click('Search');
```

It appears I'm signaling to SimpleTest that I don't want any checkboxes.  However, I've built other tests using other sets of multi-value checkboxes on this same form.  They don't have this problem.

Your thoughts?

Comment: My suggestion is to submit it as a bug to the simpletest svn repository with this test case.

Comment: I've been ignoring the issue, but when I pick it up again I will try for a test case that can be replicated ... then maybe try a bounty here before posting as bug.  Thanks for the reply.